# Is there a variation of optional<T> consistent with the behavior of T* const?

Tags: c++, constants, option-type

Is there a way to force `std::optional` not to allow rebinding value after initialization while allowing non-const access to its value? If no, is there any libraries providing an optional type with this behavior?

Here is a comparison table of allowed operations on pointers and optionals with different `const` specifiers:

```
type                      t = nullptr   *t = ...
---------------------------------------
T*                        yes           yes
T const*                  yes           no
T* const                  no            yes
T const* const            no            no

type                      t = nullopt   *t = ...
------------------------------------------------
optional<T>               yes           yes
optional<const T>         yes           no
optional<T> const         no          ! no !
optional<const T> const   no            no
```

Here is a code snippet confirming above table:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_const = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

int* p1;
std::optional<int> o1;

static_assert(!is_const<decltype(p1)>);
static_assert(!is_const<decltype(o1)>);
static_assert(!is_const<decltype(*p1)>);
static_assert(!is_const<decltype(*o1)>);

int const* p2;
std::optional<const int> o2;

static_assert(!is_const<decltype(p2)>);
static_assert(!is_const<decltype(o2)>);
static_assert(is_const<decltype(*p2)>);
static_assert(is_const<decltype(*o2)>);

int* const p3 {};
std::optional<int> const o3 {};

static_assert(is_const<decltype(p3)>);
static_assert(is_const<decltype(o3)>);
static_assert(!is_const<decltype(*p3)>);
static_assert(!is_const<decltype(*o3)>); // uh-oh

int const* const p4 {};
std::optional<const int> const o4 {};

static_assert(is_const<decltype(p4)>);
static_assert(is_const<decltype(o4)>);
static_assert(is_const<decltype(*p4)>);
static_assert(is_const<decltype(*o4)>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/v3n01a

Comment: Not without cheating with casting, and it looks like this is by design.  The dereference operators for const references only return const references. Same issue for the `value` methods.

Comment: An `optional` is not a pointer.  It's more like a `struct Holder { T held_object; };`, but with all the fancy template magic.